# I thought using a percentage in margin would be responsive

Tags: html, css, center, margin, percentage

So at this moment, I'm trying to center the 3 social media icons in the footer of the website nicely.

So instead of using margin and pixels, which would not be responsive when viewed on smaller screens ofcourse, I tried using percentages, I thought this made it responsive. I always thought the percentage of the screen would be calculated, resulting in always the same percentage distance on different screens with different widths..

As you can see on the website (http://riksblog.com/Marnik/index.html) this is clearly not the case when resizing..

Can someone please clear out how to make it responsive and why the combination of percentages and margin isn't correctly working when resizing?

How can I always make sure the 3 logo's are centered on every device?

Solution to center multiple images in a footer and a margin between them:

```css
.footer {
  width: 100%;
}

.logo-container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 320px;
  text-align: center;
 /* you can set this to the lowest bound, 
  * or you can change this based on breakpoint
  */
}

.logo {
  margin: 0 10px; /*or whatever spacing you need*/
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
   <div class="logo-container">
     <img src="logo/path" class="logo">
     <img src="logo/path" class="logo">
     <img src="logo/path" class="logo">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The percentage is based of the parent container width.

Here, if you want them to always be centered you could put them into a parent container and then give that a width, then have that set to margin auto to center it.

so something like this should work

## html

```
<div class="footer">
   <div class="logo-container">
     <img src="logo/path" class="logo">
     <img src="logo/path" class="logo">
     <img src="logo/path" class="logo">
   </div>
</div>
```

## css

```
.footer {
  width: 100%;
}

.logo-container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 320px;
  text-align: center;
 /* you can set this to the lowest bound, 
  * or you can change this based on breakpoint
  */
}

.logo {
  margin: 0 10px; /*or whatever spacing you need*/
}
```

As stated in the comments you could either set the width to the minimum width (assuming it fits to the smallest screen size/etc). Above we're doing 2 things. 1 putting the images in a container, and then having them center w/ text-align: center. Then we take that container, and center align it using margin:auto.

here's an ex fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7med35md/

Comment: Thank you for the interesting information and your example, @Brodie. I was hoping I was able calculate the width each time for each device automatically, but I guess I'll have to make a few media-queries for different screen sizes then..

Comment: If you want to do this, you could use JS to grab the screen width. Also, with the above method, assuming you are only going to have 3 items int he footer that you want centered at all times. You can make the items' parent container whatever the smallest width you want to support, and that should work out fine. For this, media queries seem like a good idea, because then you can do things like respace/resize the icons at certain widths :D

Answer (score 0):

From the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties)

> `<percentage>`
>
> The percentage is calculated with respect to the ***width*** of the generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for ***'margin-top'*** and ***'margin-bottom'*** as well. If the containing block's width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1.

See also http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/calculate-css-percentage-margins/ for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

For this you should use media-query Media Queries is a CSS3 module allowing content rendering to adapt to conditions such as screen resolution  It's  a W3C recommended standard and is a cornerstone technology of Responsive web design.
media-query allows you to write different CSS's for different screen sizes.The link of website you gave also using @media query.So u should learn and use it if you want such responsive design "make sure the 3 logo's are centered on every device".@media query allows you to do that.